# What is an example of non-Kahler 2 dimensional(complex sense) compact manifold with $b_1=0$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

This is related to the following statement. Let $S\subset P^3$ be degree $h$ smooth hypersurface. Then use degree $h$ embedding of $i:P^3\to P^N$ with $N$ appropriately choosen according to $h$. One obtains $S\to P^N$ embedding and this makes $S$ being a submanifold of $P^N$ cut out by $i(P^3)\cap H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane in $P^N$. Now it follows from Leftschetz theorem that $H^1(P^3,C)\cong H^1(S,C)$ and $H^1(P^3,C)=0\implies H^1(S,C)=0\implies H^0(S,\Omega^1)=0$.(The last step follows from Kahlerian condition and application of Hodge decomposition Theorem.)

The book claims that if $S$ is a 2-dimensional compact complex manifold(non-Kahler) and $H^1(S,C)=0$, then $H^0(S,\Omega^1)=0$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The example of non-Kahler compact complex surface given in the book is Hopf surface like $S^1\times S^{2n-1}$.(In this case, I could choose $n=2$ which yields a complex 2 dimensional manifold.) However, from Kunneth formula, I see $H^1(S^1\times S^3)=H^1(S^1)\otimes H^0(S^3)\oplus H^0(S^1)\otimes H^1(S^3)=Z$ with $Z$ coefficients.) So I do not know whether there is such an example. What is the example of 2 complex dimensional compact non-Kahler manifold with $H^1(S,C)=0$?

Ref. Kodaira, Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structures Chpt 3, Sec 6 (d) Surfaces in $P^3$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57535/examples-of-non-kahler-surfaces-with-explicit-non-kahler-metric

Comment: @KReiser My bad, I knew that example already and I forgot to put down the further constraint $H^1(S,C)=0$ which rules out that example.

Comment: @KReiser I found this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1668216. I guess the book did not say $b_1$ being even is sufficient to determine kahler. And in this case, it is already kahler. Hence, the result follows as well. Is this correct?

Comment: By my reading, it would seem so. I think it might be best to answer your own question and cite the linked post you found.

Comment: @KReiser Ah, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the post [Compact complex surfaces with $h^{1,0} < h^{0,1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/compact-complex-surfaces-with-h1-0-h0-1/1668216#1668216), for complex compact surfaces, $X$ is Kahler iff $b_1(X)$ is even.

In the setting of the book, $b_1(S)=0$. Since it is already compact complex surface, one deduces that $S$ is Kahler. Hence, there is no such example of non-Kahler compact complex surfaces with $b_1=0$.

Comment: [Here is one proof of this fact about complex surfaces](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1999__49_1_287_0.pdf), which does not rely on the classification results of Enriques-Kodair (it is also mentioned in the post you link).

Comment: @Danu Thanks a lot.